How should I calculate compound interest in Solana programs?
I am doing the exercise from the Solana lending protocol video from YouTube, and would like to calculate compound interest, ensuring:

Good floating point accuracy
My program works within CU limits

Using E versus iterating

E is an irrational number and a float and will therefore be less precise. The results below show slightly different results for E versus iterating using Decimals.
Iterating seems to be more CU intensive - if I try say 500 periods instead of 120 I'll get a CU error.

Using Decimal versus f64
While the example uses f64, I believe Decimal to be more accurate. But does Decimal math even work on Solana? An LLM (I know, it may have made this up) says:

While Rust is the primary language for Solana programs, rust_decimal isn't directly compatible with Solana's environment [1]. Solana programs typically use the standard Rust types for numerical operations, and integrating a library like rust_decimal would require significant adaptation.

However at least on localhost I was able to get the Decimal crate running.
What's the best way to calculate compound interest on Solana?
I have a working program showing the differences in each approach. It's possible there may be other approaches I should consider.
interest_rates.rs
use std::f64::consts::E;

use rust_decimal::prelude::ToPrimitive;
use rust_decimal::{Decimal, RoundingStrategy};

pub fn get_final_balance_using_decimal(
    initial_balance: u64,
    elapsed_periods: u64,
    interest_rate_basis_points: u64,
) -> u64 {
    let initial_balance_decimal: Decimal = Decimal::from(initial_balance);
    let interest_rate_decimal: Decimal =
        Decimal::from(interest_rate_basis_points) / Decimal::from(10_000);

    let mut final_balance = initial_balance_decimal;
    for _ in 0..elapsed_periods {
        final_balance = final_balance
            .checked_add(
                final_balance
                    .checked_mul(interest_rate_decimal)
                    .unwrap()
                    .round_dp_with_strategy(2, RoundingStrategy::MidpointNearestEven),
            )
            .unwrap();
    }
    final_balance.to_u64().unwrap()
}

pub fn get_final_balance_using_e(
    initial_balance: u64,
    elapsed_periods: u64,
    interest_rate_basis_points: u64,
) -> u64 {
    let multiplier =
        E.powf(interest_rate_basis_points as f64 * elapsed_periods as f64 / 10_000 as f64);
    (initial_balance as f64 * multiplier) as u64
}


lib.rs
mod interest_rates;
use interest_rates::{get_final_balance_using_decimal, get_final_balance_using_e};

use anchor_lang::prelude::*;
declare_id!("5S8qdNZWGD2wpcg4fEmgutHgvnCjYZezamirN5TdJh9g");

#[program]
pub mod test_decimals {

    use super::*;

    pub fn compare_interest_techniques(_ctx: Context<CompareInterestTechniques>) -> Result<()> {
        const INITIAL_BALANCE: u64 = 100_000;
        // 120 OK, 500 will kill the Decimal technique
        const PERIODS: u64 = 120;
        const INTEREST_RATE_BASIS_POINTS: u64 = 2;
        let final_balance_using_decimal =
            get_final_balance_using_decimal(INITIAL_BALANCE, PERIODS, INTEREST_RATE_BASIS_POINTS);
        let final_balance_using_e =
            get_final_balance_using_e(INITIAL_BALANCE, PERIODS, INTEREST_RATE_BASIS_POINTS);
        msg!(
            "Final balances using decimal: {:?} and using E: {:?}",
            final_balance_using_decimal,
            final_balance_using_e
        );
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct CompareInterestTechniques {}

test-decimals.ts
import * as anchor from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { Program } from "@coral-xyz/anchor";
import { TestDecimals } from "../target/types/test_decimals";
import { getLogs } from "@solana-developers/helpers";
import { expect } from "chai";

describe("test_decimals", () => {
  // Configure the client to use the local cluster.
  anchor.setProvider(anchor.AnchorProvider.env());

  const connection = anchor.getProvider().connection;

  const program = anchor.workspace.TestDecimals as Program<TestDecimals>;

  it("Logs the different interest calculations!", async () => {
    const tx = await program.methods.compareInterestTechniques().rpc();
    const logs = await getLogs(connection, tx);
    console.log("Your transaction signature", tx);
    console.log("Your logs", logs);
  });
});

Solana logs
  test_decimals
Your transaction signature dqZMFHam3YxcmYBGh8xcnyBXaWXhuKo9nkjQYa4tuAm4ey89mNEucFHkW9aG6rQCvKyThk1rW9icaiRay3ir5VZ
Your logs [
  'Program 5S8qdNZWGD2wpcg4fEmgutHgvnCjYZezamirN5TdJh9g invoke [1]',
  'Program log: Instruction: CompareInterestTechniques',
  'Program log: Final balances using decimal: 102428 and using E: 102429',
  'Program 5S8qdNZWGD2wpcg4fEmgutHgvnCjYZezamirN5TdJh9g consumed 63666 of 200000 compute units',
  'Program 5S8qdNZWGD2wpcg4fEmgutHgvnCjYZezamirN5TdJh9g success'
]


The problem with floating point numbers is that they lose precision the bigger or smaller the number. In solana land, I would not use them. Instead, I'd use something like this (copy and paste implementation): https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/blob/master/libraries/math/src/precise_number.rs
As for using rust_decimal, I would feel very hesitant using a plug and play third party library for calculations in a Solana Program. It's probably fine, but for mission critical code, I personally would not use it and handroll something. Or clone the lib into whatever repo I was working on and leave out the dependancy.
